# use rejection method under monte carlo to solve an inetgral in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use rejection method under Monte Carlo in R to solve the value of integration of the function:

```
f <- function(x){
      abs((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3
    }
```

The limits of the integration is `[0,Inf]`

I am using the following codes:

```
set.seed(1234)
sampled_x = runif(1000,0,1)
accept = c()
for(i in 1:length(sampled_x)){
  U = runif(1, 0, 1)
  if(dunif(sampled_x[i], 0, 1)*3*U <= dbeta(sampled_x[i], 6, 3)) {

    accept[i] = 'Yes'
  }
  else if(dunif(sampled_x[i],0,1)*2*U > dbeta(sampled_x[i], 6, 3)) {
    accept[i] = 'No'
  }
}
T = data.frame(sampled_x, accept = factor(accept, levels= c('Yes','No')))
n<-length(T)
for (i in 1:n) {
x<-runif(n)
I<-sum(f(x))
}
I
```

However, I have realized that my solution is apparently wrong. 
Kindly help me to correct it.

The main issue is to use rejection method under Monte Carlo to solve the numerical value of the integral between `0` and `Inf.` I would appreciate if the solution involve calculating the area under the curve using the dots.

Regards